# ¿Cambiar texto ComboBox Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Estoy ocupando este codigo para generar un ComboBox pero en la pantalla me sale "*choose an item*" quiero cambierselo.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Tempso" 

              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="55" 
              Margin="70,243,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="205" 

              >

        <ComboBoxItem Content="4/4" Tag="1"/>
```

Comment: si entiendo lo que pregunta quizas pueda usar Text="" para ello, le dejo un link -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos propiedades que tiene esos textos (no se cual de los dos queres cambiar)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Tempso" 
      PlaceholderText="Algun texto" 
      PickerFlyoutBase.Title="Texto cambiado"
```